# In What table in Drupal is the current version of core (Drupal) stored?

Tags: mysql, drupal

In What table in Drupal is the current version of core (Drupal) stored? I'm looking for a string like 6.2.3.

I don't see it in the system table.

Comment: From the top of my hat: it's stored in the PHP files, not in the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

6.2.3? Current is Drupal 6.15. 
**Answer**: system table, seek name="system" row, unserialize "info" field, or seek text in this field text like "version";s:4:"6.15"
Also CHANGELOG.txt file you can investigate.
Also see any *.info file in modules folder.

Answer (score 0):

Also look for this code in system.module:
`define('VERSION', '6.19');`